# How to Reset the Ticker in CreateJS

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

I am working on a game using createjs. But I am stuck in a situation.
My game has the the logic for timed mode. The game should reset every 30 seconds. But for some reasons I am unable to achieve that.
I am getting the time lapsed as follows:

```
var time_elapsed = createjs.Ticker.getTime(true);
```

For resetting I am using:

```
createjs.Ticker.reset();
```

I am unable to reset the Ticker to 0 after 30 seconds.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/Dmk3v/) is the fiddle for this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hm, the reset() seems to break it, if you just use init() it worked for me, give that a try - maybe that'll be good enough for your game for now.

Comment: @olsn calling init() doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Yes, sorry my bad I just did a very quick check, but it is just counting up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a quick look in the source-code: You need to set `createjs.Ticker._inited = false;` before you use another  `createje.Ticker.init();`

However this is a "private" attribute, so this might have some side-effect, I updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Dmk3v/4/

A more elegant way to solve your issue would probably be to use your own counter just to capture the elapsed times and reset this one instead of resetting the `createjs.Ticker`

Comment: Thanks for the research. You are right as it was a bug in createJs code which has been fixed in new release at http://community.createjs.com/discussions/createjs/1936/r?go=aHR0cHM6Ly9naXRodWIuY29tL0NyZWF0ZUpTL0Vhc2VsSlMvY29tbWl0Lzk5NTNhOWM4MWZjYWFkOTVmOGQ0OGMwMDYxYTU0OGEzZDdlNDJkODM=

Here is the official discussion: http://community.createjs.com/discussions/createjs/1936-reset-the-ticker-in-createjs